# How to build terrace security gate in a way that wind won't lift the metal roof

Tags: roof, shed, water-damage, damage, wind

Please find my terrace shed in the below image.

It has two openings.

I think I can brick one side and keep a ventilator and on the other side I can simply keep a grill gate and keep **Polycarbonate sheet** behind that.

[image]

Because I use polycarbonate sheet , I can remove the Polycarbonate sheet when there's severe cyclone so the incoming wind will have a way to go outside and roof will not be lifted.

Please see the incoming way to shed in the below pics

[image]

[image]

Please note in the below picture there's a toilet and it has ventilator

[image]

I have to lock the access to terrace because if kids are present in the terrace without any adult it can be problematic.

Comment: Why the polycarbonate sheet? Typically do you want the barrier blocking wind, containing heat, etc.? Why not just a grill grate spaced tightly enough to prevent the passage of children (4" is a space that even infants cannot get through).

Comment: I thought of using polycarbonate sheet so that when it rains what can't get in and steps won't get slippery

Comment: They want it to *not* block the wind otherwise the roof could get ripped off by air coming up the staircase. - Custom fab wrought iron with 4" spacing, with tabs attached to secure with tapcons. Or go up and down alleys looking for discarded security window bars, before the scrappers get 'em.

Comment: What about an ordinary door with the top 6" missing? The top 12" missing? Would that be enough to relieve any pressure differential? But if you're going to be there to remove the polycarbonate sheet, then why not just mechanically restrain an ordinary door in the open position during cyclones? Or remove the door from its hinges during cyclones?